# Reading from custom file name

Tags: python, filereader

I'm trying to understand how the whole thing in Python works. I want to ask the user for "ID" and then to read from a .py file with the "ID" name.

for example: the user insert "361" and the code will open "361.py" and get variables from that file

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show that you've attempted to solve the problem you are having?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/5386938

Answer (score 0):

Mainfile:

```
import ID_361
a = input('Enter Code: ')
if a  =='361':
    ID_361.ID_361()
```

ID_361:

```
def ID_361():
    print('OK')
```

**The files have to be in the same directory!**

But can you say for what you need it? It gives way more easier ways

**Better:**

Mainfile:

```
import IDs
a = input('Enter Code: ')
if a  =='361':
    IDs.ID_361()
elif a  =='362':
    IDs.ID_362()
elif a  =='363':
    IDs.ID_363()
```

IDs:

```
def ID_361():
    print('OK 361')
def ID_362():
    print('OK 362')
def ID_363():
    print('OK 363')
```

**Pros:** You only have 2 files and not like 100 which makes it clear

Comment: well, if there are 1000 IDs it makes it a lot harder haha. my thinking went to something like `id = input("what is your ID?") import id` which obviously doesn't work

Comment: I'm trying to create a kind of "users" system and give each user different parameters. then if for example I want to get the user's age I just go to his file and read `age` variable

Comment: @BennyKerido yeah I know what you mean, but you have to use a function. Then it doesn't matter if you have all definitions in one file or for each definition in a single file. What you can do if you only want to use it like a database you can write the data in a file (which is complicated) or do it with a dictionary like this `database={'id1':{id1},'id2':{id2}}` and with the user ids like this `id1={'age':21,'name':'user1234'}
` Help: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) I hope I can help you with that